# I have my old files that I worked on visible in github but, missing in visual code. How do I restore these file on visual code studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github, directory

My file on my github appears fine. But, these files and folders no longer exist on my visual code.who can be done to restore them?

Can I copy them from github to make new files on visual code and commit?
Will that affect the files already existing on my github?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Do you have local changes that you want to undo?  You can revert uncommitted changes in Git, you can delete your local repository and re-clone from GitHub, etc.  None of this is really related to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that you have done some valuable changes on your local that you will need, but you had some unfortunate changes on your local that would harm your repo.

I will assume that you have this folder structure:

```
myprojects
    myrepo
```

Let's navigate out from myrepo:

```
cd ..
```

and run

```
git clone git@<yourrepopath> myrepo2
```

So now your folder structure is

```
myprojects
    myrepo
    myrepo2
```

Now, using myrepo2 as a source and myrepo as a destination, copy back the files and folders you removed.